# Convert timestamp and timezone into RFC3339 format

Tags: go, time

I am taking timestamp from the user like this

```
2015-05-28T17:00:00
```

And a timezone `"America/Los_Angeles"`
Now I want  convert the date into something like

```
2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00
```

Is that possible in go ,Please help me out in this ,if you have any links which you can share

Comment: https://gobyexample.com/time

Comment: You can use `ParseInLocation` so you can parse given timestamp in your timezeone, I will add an answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ParseInLocation`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#example-ParseInLocation) to parse datetime in specific location.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    loc, err := time.LoadLocation("America/Los_Angeles")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Note: without explicit zone, returns time in given location.
    const shortForm = "2015-05-28T17:00:00"
    t, err := time.ParseInLocation("2006-01-02T15:04:05", shortForm, loc)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Its output is:

```
2015-05-28 17:00:00 -0700 PDT
```

Answer (score 0):

"timezone" translates to `time.Location` in go. To load a location by name:

```
loc, err := time.LoadLocation("America/Los_Angeles")
```

Parsing:

- to interpret the string as "that timestamp in that location":

  ```
  t, err := time.ParseInLocation("2006-01-02T15:04:05", input, loc)
  ```
- to interpret the string as "that timestamp in UTC":

  ```
  t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05", input)
  ```

Formatting:

to format t according to RFC3339 :

```
fmt.Println(t.Format(time.RFC3339))
```

`t` carries its own time.Location, you can also translate that timestamp to the timezone you see fit:

```
fmt.Println(t.In(loc).Format(time.RFC3339))
fmt.Println(t.UTC().Format(time.RFC3339))
```

https://go.dev/play/p/g2BgfdYGxU_I